# Simple and efficient way to compare $BASH_VERSION to a specified version

Tags: bash

Zsh has the very handy `is-at-least` utility.

```
is-at-least 5.7 && echo "You're using a version of Zsh above 5.7" || echo "You're running an old Zshell version.  Upgrade, dude."
```

How can this be done in Bash?  (It must be in a simple way that takes into account that version numbers can have 2 "decimal" points, and that 1.25 is higher than 1.3, unlike with decimal notation for normal numbers.)

Comment: You want to compare 1.25 against 3 or 5.7 against something else? It is not clear

Comment: @David I guess OP is looking to compare versions of Bash and not just get it

Comment: If the linked question does not provide a solution, drop a comment and I'm happy to reopen -- but there are eight very good answers there.

Comment: @Inian - yes, I checked, the answers in the linked question *compare* against a target version after getting the current version. The answer by FelixEnescu looks quite good.